Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions
I created an .NET Core 8 console application. When I try to generate a migration, I get this error:

Error: Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[HealthCheck.Console.Context.SystemHealthContext]' while attempting to activate 'HealthCheck.Console.Context.SystemHealthContext'.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Here is my DbContext class
public class SystemHealthContext : DbContext
{
    public SystemHealthContext(DbContextOptions<SystemHealthContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<ServerMasterInfo> ServerMasterInfo { get; set; }
}

Here is my program class where register mydbcontext
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

var services = new ServiceCollection();

var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");


services.AddDbContext<SystemHealthContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));

services.AddTransient<SystemHealthCheck>();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
var systemHealthCheck = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<SystemHealthCheck>();

Migration error details:

Thanks in advance

Make sure you have the Tools package installed?
dotnet add package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

@SamFessler I have installed the tool Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.But it cannot solve the issue

You could try configure the connectionstring inside Dbcontext
    public class SystemHealthContext : DbContext
    {
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(AppContext.BaseDirectory)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                .Build();

            var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DbConnection");
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        }

        public DbSet<ServerMasterInfo> ServerMasterInfo { get; set; }
    }

Then in program.cs
services.AddDbContext<SystemHealthContext>();

